# Moving down a div ala Apple 

Tags: javascript

any ideas on how to move down a div like the apple bar at the top? (jQuery or other libs?)

Example: http://www.apple.com/ipad/guided-tours/

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "move down a div"

Comment: You can find everything you need to know about jQuery effects here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: wait i make a video to show the effect

Comment: here the video to show the effect: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2mrbfx2&s=7 (what kind of old browser are you using? xD)

Comment: yes123: CSS Transitions are still a working draft. They're not even *meant* to be widely deployed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple uses CSS transitions, put them on the element you want to move and then dynamically (with javascript for example) change the CSS property you have put the animation on ('top' for example). Et voila.

Older browsers won't show the animation, but that's okay as it won't destroy usability. We're living in the progressive enhancement age nowadays.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions
- http://www.webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/

Comment: Wow does apple uses it to move down the bar?

Comment: @yes: Check it out with Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with the `top` CSS property. Play around with it, it can do much more than that :).

Alternatively, you can use CSS3 Transitions, which is supported in FF, Opera and Webkit (Chrome, Safari). You can find some docs for example on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions). You can check which browsers support it [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions).

Answer (score 0):

I like the CSS transitions method but the pragmatist in me remembers the effect of the top navigation dropping in can also be easily done with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#nav").slideDown("fast");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

To get a fancy bounce effect you will need to additionally include jQuery UI with easing methods (in Effects Core).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#nav").slideDown("fast", "easeOutBounce");
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/download - be sure to include Effects Core

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ - The easing methods are documented here

Comment: this isn't the same.. slideDown "expand" the div, it doens't move down